# Laravel return property from third table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have three tables:

```
products
product_types
product_categories
```

`products` belongs to `product_types` and `product_types` belongs to `product_categories`.

How can I access a column from `product_categories` from `products`?:

**ProductTypes model:**

```
class ProductTypes extends Eloquent {

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProductCategories');
    }

}
```

**Products model:**

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function brands() {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProductBrands', 'brand_id', 'id');
    }

    public function ages() {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProductAges', 'age_id', 'id');
    }

    public function types() {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProductTypes', 'type_id', 'id');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductImages');
    }

    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductReviews');
    }

    public function toArray() {

        $ar = $this->attributes;

        $ar['brand'] = $this->brand;
        $ar['age'] = $this->age;
        $ar['type'] = $this->type;

        return $ar;
    }

    public function getBrandAttribute() {
        $brands = $this->brands()->first();
        return (isset($brands->brand) ? $brands->brand : '');
    }

    public function getAgeAttribute() {
        $ages = $this->ages()->first();
        return (isset($ages->age) ? $ages->age : '');
    }

    public function getTypeAttribute() {
        $types = $this->types()->first();
        return (isset($types->type) ? $types->type : '');
    }

}
```

I have tried:

```
$productData->types()->category()->category
```

But this gives an error saying the method doesn't exist.

Sorry about the title, couldn't think of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you're not executing the query when doing `types()` and therefore you're calling `category()` on the query builder instance and not the `ProductTypes` model.

You can use the dynamic properties for accessing the *result* of the relationship.

```
$productData->types->category->category
```

---

Also consider renaming your relationships. Currently you have "types" for example but it only returns one type, because its a one-to-many relation. "type" would make more sense.